# How to move 2nd array formula in the same column if the 1st array has a spill error in google sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have two array formulas that repeat dates n number of times in the same column. Both of them could be dynamic so the 1st array could extend into the territory where the other array is currently causing a split error.

My question is there a way to write this array formula as one formula? Or is there some other method by which this can be done?

[image]

Comment: Please remove either one ink or the other. Your links are ready in the question and are not duplicated.

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add a table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure.  If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455/) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Comment: Please include formulas as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple way, given what I can see in your screenshots would be to contain both query formulas within another array formula and separate them with a semi-colon. This will stack them vertically. Essentially, it should look something like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({QUERY1;QUERY2})
```